# how to extract lines between 2 patterns, and save them to different files

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Suppose we have this file:

```
rrows 35 cols 51  spin 2 %band5 efermi=0.012538
0.004352  0.004317  0.004213  0.004047  0.003828  0.003570  0.003291  0.003011
0.002754  0.002544  0.002408  0.002376  0.002478  0.002742  0.003200  0.003882
0.004818  0.006034  0.007560  0.009420  0.011637  0.014209  0.017205  0.020617
0.024458  0.028717  0.024458  0.020617  0.017205  0.014209  0.011637  0.009420
0.007560  0.006034  0.004818  0.003882  0.003200  0.002742  0.002478  0.002376
0.002408  0.002544  0.002754  0.003011  0.003291  0.003570  0.003828  0.004047
0.004213  0.004317  0.004352
0.004339  0.004087  0.003978  0.003805  0.003576  0.003305  0.003009  0.002708
0.002425  0.002184  0.002011  0.001934  0.001979  0.002172  0.002538  0.003096
0.003855  0.004930  0.006453  0.008311  0.010524  0.013114  0.016097  0.019488
0.023300  0.027520  0.023300  0.019488  0.016096  0.013113  0.010523  0.008310
0.006452  0.004928  0.003856  0.003097  0.002539  0.002173  0.001979  0.001934
0.002012  0.002185  0.002426  0.002709  0.003009  0.003305  0.003576  0.003805
0.003979  0.004088  0.004339
rrows 35 cols 51  spin 2 %band7 efermi=0.012538
-0.083687 -0.083837 -0.084283 -0.085015 -0.086017 -0.087265 -0.088733 -0.090386
-0.092190 -0.094103 -0.096082 -0.098082 -0.100055 -0.101950 -0.103713 -0.105283
-0.106592 -0.107556 -0.108073 -0.108026 -0.107336 -0.106094 -0.106755 -0.107283
-0.106405 -0.108146 -0.106406 -0.107280 -0.106757 -0.106094 -0.107335 -0.108024
-0.108070 -0.107553 -0.106589 -0.105280 -0.103710 -0.101947 -0.100052 -0.098079
-0.096079 -0.094100 -0.092187 -0.090384 -0.088731 -0.087264 -0.086016 -0.085014
-0.084283 -0.083837 -0.083687
-0.085767 -0.085905 -0.086315 -0.086988 -0.087910 -0.089061 -0.090418 -0.091950
-0.093626 -0.095410 -0.097264 -0.099147 -0.101017 -0.102829 -0.104540 -0.106099
-0.107455 -0.108548 -0.109305 -0.109631 -0.109407 -0.108549 -0.107204 -0.105849
-0.106353 -0.108175 -0.106354 -0.105851 -0.107205 -0.108549 -0.109406 -0.109630
-0.109304 -0.108546 -0.107453 -0.106097 -0.104537 -0.102827 -0.101015 -0.099145
-0.097262 -0.095409 -0.093625 -0.091949 -0.090417 -0.089060 -0.087909 -0.086987
-0.086314 -0.085905 -0.085767
rrows 35 cols 51  spin 2 %band9 efermi=0.012538
-0.061113 -0.061436 -0.062390 -0.063941 -0.066032 -0.068592 -0.071540 -0.074790
-0.078249 -0.081826 -0.085425 -0.088945 -0.092274 -0.095281 -0.097398 -0.099381
-0.100501 -0.101364 -0.104053 -0.105697 -0.106070 -0.105020 -0.103471 -0.105104
-0.106376 -0.107276 -0.106378 -0.105107 -0.103474 -0.105024 -0.106076 -0.105700
-0.104061 -0.101373 -0.100495 -0.099380 -0.097396 -0.095273 -0.092266 -0.088937
-0.085418 -0.081819 -0.078243 -0.074784 -0.071535 -0.068587 -0.066028 -0.063938
-0.062388 -0.061435 -0.061113
-0.067212 -0.067480 -0.068275 -0.069570 -0.071323 -0.073481 -0.075980 -0.078749
-0.081714 -0.084796 -0.087914 -0.090982 -0.093903 -0.096572 -0.098857 -0.100599
-0.101611 -0.101720 -0.104006 -0.106581 -0.107862 -0.107418 -0.105241 -0.104975
-0.106487 -0.107607 -0.106490 -0.104977 -0.105243 -0.107422 -0.107868 -0.106588
-0.104013 -0.101715 -0.101604 -0.100592 -0.098850 -0.096565 -0.093896 -0.090975
-0.087908 -0.084790 -0.081708 -0.078744 -0.075975 -0.073477 -0.071320 -0.069567
-0.068273 -0.067479 -0.067212
```

TO

file1:

```
0.004352  0.004317  0.004213  0.004047  0.003828  0.003570  0.003291  0.003011
0.002754  0.002544  0.002408  0.002376  0.002478  0.002742  0.003200  0.003882
0.004818  0.006034  0.007560  0.009420  0.011637  0.014209  0.017205  0.020617
0.024458  0.028717  0.024458  0.020617  0.017205  0.014209  0.011637  0.009420
0.007560  0.006034  0.004818  0.003882  0.003200  0.002742  0.002478  0.002376
0.002408  0.002544  0.002754  0.003011  0.003291  0.003570  0.003828  0.004047
0.004213  0.004317  0.004352
0.004339  0.004087  0.003978  0.003805  0.003576  0.003305  0.003009  0.002708
0.002425  0.002184  0.002011  0.001934  0.001979  0.002172  0.002538  0.003096
0.003855  0.004930  0.006453  0.008311  0.010524  0.013114  0.016097  0.019488
0.023300  0.027520  0.023300  0.019488  0.016096  0.013113  0.010523  0.008310
0.006452  0.004928  0.003856  0.003097  0.002539  0.002173  0.001979  0.001934
0.002012  0.002185  0.002426  0.002709  0.003009  0.003305  0.003576  0.003805
0.003979  0.004088  0.004339
```

file2:

```
-0.083687 -0.083837 -0.084283 -0.085015 -0.086017 -0.087265 -0.088733 -0.090386
-0.092190 -0.094103 -0.096082 -0.098082 -0.100055 -0.101950 -0.103713 -0.105283
-0.106592 -0.107556 -0.108073 -0.108026 -0.107336 -0.106094 -0.106755 -0.107283
-0.106405 -0.108146 -0.106406 -0.107280 -0.106757 -0.106094 -0.107335 -0.108024
-0.108070 -0.107553 -0.106589 -0.105280 -0.103710 -0.101947 -0.100052 -0.098079
-0.096079 -0.094100 -0.092187 -0.090384 -0.088731 -0.087264 -0.086016 -0.085014
-0.084283 -0.083837 -0.083687
-0.085767 -0.085905 -0.086315 -0.086988 -0.087910 -0.089061 -0.090418 -0.091950
-0.093626 -0.095410 -0.097264 -0.099147 -0.101017 -0.102829 -0.104540 -0.106099
-0.107455 -0.108548 -0.109305 -0.109631 -0.109407 -0.108549 -0.107204 -0.105849
-0.106353 -0.108175 -0.106354 -0.105851 -0.107205 -0.108549 -0.109406 -0.109630
-0.109304 -0.108546 -0.107453 -0.106097 -0.104537 -0.102827 -0.101015 -0.099145
-0.097262 -0.095409 -0.093625 -0.091949 -0.090417 -0.089060 -0.087909 -0.086987
-0.086314 -0.085905 -0.085767
```

And so on.

PS: `rrows 35 cols 51  spin 2 %band9 efermi=0.012538` are one in line. I want to extract the lines/columns between two `rrows 35 cols 51  spin 2 %band9 efermi=0.012538` `rrows 35 cols 51  spin 2 %band10 efermi=0.012538`

I wrote a command like this :

```
~$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {awk 'NR >= i && NR <= i+2' <bnds.fe >out_$i'};printf out_$i}'
```

which failed. Could you help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: That command hurts my eyes. Why is there a command inside another ? It doesn't even make sense in a psuedocode sort of way.

Comment: Please read the [editing guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: How does the command fail? Can you insert the error messages?

Comment: What are the names for the output files? out_1, out2, ...?

Comment: -1 !! You ask a question, wait for answer, then chnage the question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
< input awk '/^rrows/ {i++; next} {print >> "file"i}'
```

Comment: it works! while it generate some empty files...

Comment: sorry again, what does  "%band[0-9][0-9]*" mean? why twice [0-9]?

Comment: @WeiweiSun Because the input looked different before you formatted it, I tought everything was on a single line. Let me fix this

Comment: @WeiweiSun Check the update, it should work now

Comment: hej Kos, things becomes complicated when the data is composed of multi columns, lines... How to deal with it?

Comment: @WeiweiSun I should see an example, however since you are new to the site, I think I should explain you that this is not a forum, meaning that different questions should be asked on different questions. If what you're talking about it's a *mere* variation of the example above, than just provide an example in which the script breaks by [editing your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/214176/edit), but if this is a further problem due to an expansion of which the original requirements were, then [ask a new question instead](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @WeiweiSun In any case you can let me know when you did either things by leaving a comment here, and I'll take a look

Comment: it is ready now, I hope that I have explained it clearly....

Comment: @WeiweiSun I used `awk` this time, check the update